# Delphi 7 dde callback on windows 7 - 64 bits

Tags: windows, delphi, 64-bit, dde

We have a delphi 7 dde client application that communicates with a dde server from another company ( ISIS Papyrus printing system )
Both are 32 bits and works fine on windows 7 32 bits.

Now our company is switching to windows 7 64 bits and the communication between the client and server doesn't work good anymore.
We use a callback function with DdeInitialize

We use this because we want to know when the process done by the server is really finnished and the document is generated.

On windows 7 64bits we get roubbish data for PTMonMsgStruct(pData)^.wMsg

Anyone knows whats goes wrong ?

Code :

```
DdeInitialize(FDdeInstId, SVDdeCallBack, MF_POSTMSGS + MF_SENDMSGS, 0);
```

and the SVDdeCallBack

```
function SVDdeCallBack(
   CallType, Fmt : UINT; //transaction type ; format atom of the data sent from the server
   Conv: HConv;          //a handle the conversation
   hsz1, hsz2: HSZ;      // hsz1: topic name ; hsz2: item name
   Data: HDDEData;       //a handle to the data associated with the topic and item name pair
   Data1, Data2: ULONG)  //
   : HDDEData; stdcall;
var
  pData: Pointer;
  Len: Integer;
type
  PTMonMsgStruct = ^TMonMsgStruct;
begin
  Result := 0;
  // Check if the calltype is the monitoring DDE call
    if CallType = XTYP_MONITOR then
  begin
    // Get the DDE data
        pData := DdeAccessData( Data, @Len);
    // If data
        if pData <> nil then
    begin
        // If data is a posted message
        if Data2 = MF_POSTMSGS then
      begin
                try
            // Check if the message was an acknowledge message
          //myMonitorStruct := PTMonMsgStruct(pData^);
            if PTMonMsgStruct(pData)^.wMsg = WM_DDE_ACK then
          begin
            WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallBack: TMonMsgStruct(pData^).wMsg = WM_DDE_ACK');
            WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallBack: Acknowledge message');
            // Detect only the acknowledge messages with no busy flag
              if ((PTMonMsgStruct(pData)^.dmhd.uilo and DDE_FACK) = DDE_FACK) and
               ((PTMonMsgStruct(pData)^.dmhd.uilo and DDE_FBUSY) = 0) then
            begin
                // The DDE command has terminated
              WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallback: ((TMonMsgStruct(pData^).dmhd.uilo and DDE_FACK) = DDE_FACK) and ((TMonMsgStruct(pData^).dmhd.uilo and DDE_FBUSY) = 0)');
              WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallback: Acknowledge with BUSY Flag = 0');
                    ApplData.WaitStat := False;
              WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallback: ApplData.WaitStat := False');
            end
            else
            begin
              WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallback: Acknowledge with BUSY Flag <> 0')
            end;
          end;
          if PTMonMsgStruct(pData)^.wMsg = WM_DDE_TERMINATE then
          begin
            // Check if in close
            WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallBack:TMonMsgStruct(pData^).wMsg = WM_DDE_TERMINATE');
            WriteLogFile('prcDDE.DDECallBack: DDE_terminate message');
            if not scrFrontOffice.FInClose then
               begin
                  // Check if there is a second file
                  if ((Length(ApplData.DataFile2) > 0) and (ApplData.DataFile <> ApplData.DataFile2)) then
                     begin
                        // Activate the timer
                        // 2 following commands removed by VDP -> added in PrcFrontOffice
                        if bInternWaitForView then
                           begin
                              scrFrontOffice.FTimerProcess := True;
                              scrFrontOffice.tmrClose.Enabled := True;
                           end;
                     end
                  else
                     begin
                        // The DDE connection is inactive
                        scrFrontOffice.FDDEConnectionActive := False;
                            // Close the program
                        scrFrontOffice.Close;
                     end;
               end;
          end;
                finally
            // Free the accessed data
                    DdeUnaccessData(Data);
                end;
        end
      else
      begin
        //WriteLogFile('Data is no posted message');
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      //WriteLogFile('No data received with DdeAccessData');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can we presume you check the return value of `DDEInitialize` and have verified that it is `DMLERR_NO_ERROR`?  Otherwise, likely DDE problems are often win7 installations being not up to date (some bad KBs have trashed DDE in the past), antivirus applications blocking DDE messages, bad hardware drivers, UAC issues... DDE is pretty fragile - it's almost 30 years old and has been dead for almost 20.  Not really enough information here to be able to help, unfortunately.

Comment: DDE was somewhat replaced with COM about 20 years ago. Perhaps the software has a COM automation interface of something even more modern. I had a quick look and [here](http://www.isis-papyrus.com/e15/pages/business-apps/correspondence.html) it's said that it has a _'MQ/SOAP/HTML/REST'_ interface whatever that means, I could not find any effective developer documentation rightaway.

Comment: This exact same question was asked 2 weeks ago in the Embarcadero forums: [DDECallback with Delphi 7 on win7 64 bits machine](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=119447).

Comment: Yes i know. Now the company asked me to fix it :-(

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you implementing DDE manually instead of using Delphi's `TDdeClientConv` component?

Two mistakes I see in your manual code:

1. the callback is declared incorrectly.  The `Data1` and `Data2` parameters are declared as `ULONG`, but they need to be `ULONG_PTR` instead.  See the definition on MSDN:

   [DdeCallback callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648742.aspx)

   ```
   HDDEDATA CALLBACK DdeCallback(
     _In_ UINT      uType,
     _In_ UINT      uFmt,
     _In_ HCONV     hconv,
     _In_ HSZ       hsz1,
     _In_ HSZ       hsz2,
     _In_ HDDEDATA  hdata,
     _In_ ULONG_PTR dwData1,
     _In_ ULONG_PTR dwData2
   );
   ```

   `ULONG` is always 32bit in size, even on a 64bit 
   system. `ULONG_PTR` is either 32bit or 64bit depending on whether you are 
   compiling for 32bit or 64bit. So, in this case, your callback is going to 
   truncate those parameter values if you recompile your app for 64bit.
2. the callback is looking for `XTYP_MONITOR` transactions, but `APPCLASS_MONITOR` is not included in the call to `DdeInitialize()`.

With that said, if you are getting garbage from `TMonMsgStruct`, chances are it is not declared correctly.  In Delphi 7 (and all the way up to XE), I see `TMonMsgStruct` in Delphi's `DDeml` unit is declared as a **packed** record, which means it uses byte alignment.  But in Delphi XE2, the `packed` directive was finally removed so `TMonMsgStruct` uses more natural alignment (as it should be).  So, you may have to re-declare `TMonMsgStruct` in your own code to use proper alignment (4 or 8 byte) that is compatible with 64bit systems.

**Update**: on a 32bit system, you are receiving 32bit data, and on a 64bit system you are receiving 64bit data even though your app is compiled for 32bit.  The size of `TMonMsgStruct` is 72 bytes in 32bit, and is 112 bytes in 64bit. `TMonMsgStruct` contains several fields that use data types which are 4 bytes in 32bit and 8 bytes in 64bit (namely `HWND`, `THandle`, `WPARAM`, `LPARAM`, and `UINT_PTR`). Those fields, along with alignment padding, account for the difference in sizes. So, you need to either:

1. compile a 64bit version of your app to run on 64bit systems.  You cannot do that with Delphi 7, though, you need Delphi XE2 or later.
2. have your 32bit app define a 64bit-compatible version of `TMonMsgStruct`, and then use the `Len` value returned from `DdeAccessData()` to decide whether to use the 32bit or 64bit record to access the data.

Comment: Sorry but don't know how to format the comment :-(  Thanks for you answer.  The code is compiled with delphi 7 so 32bits exe but it runs on a 64bit windows 7. I tried you suggestion with declare my own TMonMsgStruct declared as record instead of packed record. If i debug the callback function dwdata1 and dwdata2 have the same values as i see with ddespy.

Comment: It is old code which was developed by someone else not in the team anymore :-( It was working fine until the swith to windows 64bits.  I tried with the delphi components but i can't get that working.

Comment: Something else i saw when i debug on a 32 bits windows the call pData := DdeAccessData( Data, @Len); the len is 72 however when i do this on the 64 bits windows the len is 112. I try to give as much information as possible. Don't know anymore how to resomlve this problem :-(

Comment: 72 is the correct size in 32bit, and 112 is the correct size in 64bit.  `TMonMsgStruct` contains several fields that use data types which are 4 bytes in 32bit and 8 bytes in 64bit. Those fields, along with alignment padding, account for the difference in sizes. I have updated my answer with this information.